# QOpenGLWidget move context to another thread crash

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have this simple example and this program crashed when I tried to call `context()->moveToThread(render_thread_);`. Can anyone help?

```
class FrameRenderer: public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FrameRenderer(QGLCanvas *parent):m_parent(parent), QThread(){}
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QGLCanvas *m_parent;
};

class QGLCanvas : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QGLCanvas(QWidget* parent = NULL);
    ~QGLCanvas();

    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void paintGL();
    virtual void resizeGL(int width, int height);
    void DrawThreadEntry();
    FrameRenderer* render_thread_;
};


void FrameRenderer::run()
{
    m_parent->DrawThreadEntry();
}


QGLCanvas::QGLCanvas(QWidget* parent)
    : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    render_thread_ = new FrameRenderer(this);
    doneCurrent();
    context()->moveToThread(render_thread_);
    render_thread_->start();
}


void QGLCanvas::DrawThreadEntry()
{
    while(true)
    {
        makeCurrent();
        QOpenGLFunctions f;
        f.initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        f.glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        f.glFinish();
        doneCurrent();
        emit update();
    }
}
```

Comment: A basic rule in Qt is that you can only update the GUI in the main thread, called GUI thread.

Comment: @eyllanesc But it crashed when I move the context to the thread. I comment the emit line, it stilled crashed.

Comment: read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

Comment: `context()->moveToThread(render_thread_);` Hm... checked for null? QOpenGLContext *QOpenGLWidget::context() const

Returns The QOpenGLContext used by this widget or 0 if not yet initialized.

Comment: @AlexanderVX The moveToThread call starts too soon? I should use a Timer to move the context after it is created?

Comment: may be render_thread_ parent and context() parent are not same parents try this render_thread_ = new FrameRender;

Comment: @saeed this parent is just a pointer to `QOpenglWidget`.

Comment: @AlexanderVX it has been initialized...The returned pointer is not null

Comment: It seems like the problem is caused by `QOpenGLWidget` context not initialized when I tried to call `moveToThread`. It is very different from `QGLWidget`. In `QGLWidget` you can do the `moveToThread` call in constructor.

Comment: I had a problem on ios and qt. The context was not yet initiliazed, try to add a timer after you call the constructor, it worked in my case.

Comment: @DraykoonD Can you give an example code so that I can close this thread ?

Comment: I don't know if it's the solution but try someting like that QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(1000); add update() as a slot and do your moveToThread inside http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html. If it's working maybe you should try look if you can do your move ToThread inside"void QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the solution but i got a similar problem on iOS, the context was available but after a short period of time.

You can try to add a timmer and delay your call to OpenGL

.h

```
slots:
   void update();
```

.cpp

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this); 
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);
```

If it's working maybe you should try look if you can do your move ToThread inside *void QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()* which is responsible to set up the context